# Used of NROW to be able to count values in a specific interval

Tags: r

I loaded the weather database in Rattle and i was able to count the numbers of observation greater than 20 and less and equal to 20 for "Temp3pm" :

> library(rattle)
>
> g <- nrow(subset(weather, Temp3pm > 20))
>
> g

[1] 150

> s <- nrow(subset(weather, Temp3pm <= 20))
>
> s

[1] 216

My question is how can i count the number of rows that contains "No" and "Yes" for RainTomorrow because:

> m <- nrow(subset(weather, RainTomorrow = No))
>
> m

[1] 366

which is not the right answer i believe i have to either add or change the code i used to get the correct count.
Some help will be appreciated thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look for `?"=="` (compare) vs `?"="` (assign).

Try:

```
m <- nrow(subset(weather, RainTomorrow == "No"))
```